# prevent people for download files (image) from s3 amazon Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

how is possible to modify S3 bucket policy that people can see images in website but If they attempt to download images ,s3 make their request forbidden.(secure images files)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "Policyid",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Sid": "policyid",
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": "*",
           "Action": "s3:GetObject",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
           "Condition": {
               "StringLike": {
                   "aws:Referer": [
                       "http://www.mywebsite.com/*",
                       "http://mywebsite.com/*"
                   ]
               }
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: If they can see an image in the browser, the image has already been downloaded.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x239gnCxGk0 ]  this one I think his solution is old cause this is exactly the thing that Im looking for it.but Its not working for me

Comment: I see. you mean not downloading directly from S3.

Comment: yes files access for read but not possible for download

Answer (score 1):

One way to stop people downloading your objects directly from S3, instead of using your website, is through `CloudFront` and `Origin Access Identity`:

- [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Thanks to this you will be able to **stop people** from accessing your S3 objects (images) directly:

> If you restrict access by using, for example, CloudFront signed URLs or signed cookies, you also **won’t want people to be able to view files** by simply using the direct Amazon S3 URL for the file. Instead, you want them to **only access the files by using the CloudFront URL**, so your protections work.

**Full details** on how to set it up are available inthe  AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html). As part of the setup process, your **bucket policy** would have to be modified as follows (example from docs):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EH1HDMB1FH2TC"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above bucket policy ensures that only `CloudFront Origin Access Identity` can access your objects. Your users won't be able to directly do the same.

Comment: @AlirezaTorkamani No problem. Please let me know how it will go.

Comment: With this setup you can't download directly from the bucket but can still download indirectly from the bucket via the CDN *("only access the files by using the CloudFront URL")* and from the end-user perspective, that's exactly the same thing.  I'd suggest that OP is actually asking what you originally assumed, so the correct answer is -- as you already suggested in comments -- something along the lines of *"What you are attempting is impossible.  If the browser can display the image, the browser can download the image (and in fact already has)."*

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks. I think OP is aware of this. Also I think I made it clear that it protects only from downloading directly from s3, not in general.